# Как сделать всплывающую подсказку в UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Допустим пропал интернет, и необходимо чтобы снизу не на долго появилась надпись "проверьте подключение к интернету". На андроиде такое есть, а вот на Windows UWP я найти никак не могу...

Comment: Используйте событие `NetworkStatusChanged`

Comment: @WebMorda мне нужно не определить когда интернет пропал, а именно вывести это

Comment: @Denisok, мой ответ вам не подошёл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я считаю, что более правильное решение — использовать средства, предоставляемые платформой, являющиеся частью ее дизайна. В UWP для нотификаций используются плитки, бейджи и "тосты", вот именно "тосты" (`toast notifications`) и подойдут вам в этой ситуации.

Для удобного формирования разметки toast notification (а они размечаются в XML) я использую [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/), вот здесь есть несколько примеров использования пакета на все случаи жизни: [Adaptive and interactive toast notifications for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts).

Я набросал следующий класс:

```
class Toaster
{
    public static void Show()
    {
        ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent
        {
            Visual = new ToastVisual
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveText
                        {
                            Text = "Проверьте подключение к интернету"
                        }
                    },
                    AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo
                    {
                        Source = "disconnect.png",
                        HintCrop = ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        var toast = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml());
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }
}
```

Теперь из подписчика на нужное событие вы можете вызвать:

```
Toaster.Show();
```

И появится сообщение, смартфона с Windows у меня больше нету, поэтому не могу показать с него скрин, но в десктопной версии это выглядит так:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

---

Другой способ, который мне нравится меньше. Он требует чтобы все ваши `Page` имели в качестве корневого элемента любую панель (любой производный класс от `Panel`).
Добавьте в нужный обработчик следующий код:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow
        .Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    var rootPanel = ((Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Content as Page)?.Content as Panel;
    if (rootPanel == null) return;
    var tt = new ToolTip
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 50),
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
        Content = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "Проверьте подключение к интернету",
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
    };
    rootPanel.Children.Add(tt);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    rootPanel.Children.Remove(tt);
});
```

Он создает `ToolTip`, помещает его на панель, ждет секунду и удаляет его.
По хорошему шаблон тултипа нужно поместить в ресурсы `App.xaml` или в библиотеку ресурсов.

[image: ToolTip]

Comment: А секунда жёстко зашита или регулируется где?

Comment: Вы про второй пример? Там смотрите `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` но лучше использовать тосты

Comment: Я видел примеры тостов в консольной аппликации, но не собирал сам. Если приложение не UWP то вариантов не много. Вот адрес примера, кстати, тостов в не UWP приложении http://blog.plasticscm.com/2016/08/how-to-send-windows-toast-notifications.html