# Аномальный VS и оповещения windows 10

Tags: c#, windows

Пытаюсь сделать всплывающие оповещения на windows 10. Сперва VS просто отказался компилировать код, при этом никаких ошибок он графически не выделил.
Вот сам код:

```
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello World!"));

ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Я этот код взял [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx), но черт бы уже с ним. Я написал следующее:

```
XmlDocument toastXml = new XmlDocument();
toastXml.LoadXml("<toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastText02\"><text id=\"1\">Title</text><text id=\"2\">Subtitle</text></binding></visual></toast>");

ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

И, о чудо, код запустился, но...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже в бессилии. Гугл уже не помогает (вернее помогает, но вот к чему это приводит). Подскажите, что можно исправить?

Comment: Ну так выясните, на какой строке падает. Записывайте отладочную информацию в файл. Поместите код в try/catch, поймайте исключение и залогируйте. Вы ж программист!

Comment: Судя по сообщению, компилять он не отказывался. А вот винда выполнить не смогла...

Comment: Интересный факт.Сама компиляция (именно компиляция, а не запуск) происходит нормально. Программа же при этом как будто просто не видит этих строк (либо VS просто компилирует "последний успешный вариант").

Comment: Изучение эксцепшена ни к чему меня ни привело (или я не туда смотрел, там целая гора разный полей). Единственное интересное -- это Stack trace, но и он ничего подозрительного не выдал.
P.S. все падает на финальной строке -- вызове самого нотифаера.

Comment: Попробуйте способ создания тостов отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710748/218063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh802768) (а также английским [ответам](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32221222/6808809)), вам следует указать [AppUserModelID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd391569) при вызове `Toast`'а.

Цитата из документации:

> **Important**  You must include the [AppUserModelID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd391569) of your app's shortcut
>   on the Start screen each time that you call [CreateToastNotifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/br208645). If
>   you fail to do this, your toast will not be displayed.

Другими словами, вам следует попробовать такой подход: `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(**appID**).Show(toast);`

---

Также советую попробовать отловить из за чего именно происходит данная ошибка. Попробуйте к примеру подписаться на событие `Failed` перед отправкой и выведите его результат. Сам код `HRESULT: 0x80070490` обозначает (если не ошибаюсь) `Not Found`. То есть при отправке у вас не найдено что то...

Comment: Вместо appID просто вписал имя своего проекта. Как я понял, это просто некий уникальный ключ, используемый менеджером оповещений для группировки оповещений. Все заработало, но я до сих пор не могу понять, почему VS не хотел запускать код
`XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");`

Comment: @PurpleDragon А вы попробуйте в итогде посмотреть, как выглядит `XML` при таком выводе. Может структура неверная? Для проверки структуры, советую это [приложение](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/store/p/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1). Я к сожалению это у себя проверить не могу. Ну а также попробуйте все же подписаться на событие `Failed`, в теории, оно должно выдать конкретно проблему ошибки.

Comment: Я же сказал, что оповещения теперь выводятся. Просто VS отказывается компилировать определенные строки.